# Add button from code

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms, visual-studio

I'm trying to add a button to the form using code and iv'e looked it up on the internet but nothing works.

```
public void addSnake()
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Location = new Point(360, 390);
    btn.Size = new Size(10, 10);
    btn.Text = "";
    btn.Name = num + "";
    btn.Tag = this.oneD;
    btn.IsAccessible = false;
    Controls.Add(btn);
}

public Point getPoint()
{
    Button btn = (Button)Controls.Find(num + ""); 
    return this.pos; //temporary
}
```

it says "The name 'Controls' does not exist in the current context". (for both functions)

Note: the functions addSnake and getPoint are inside a Class I made

Full code here: *deleted*

Comment: Show the entire code

Comment: Is the class you made inheriting from `System.Windows.Forms.Form`? Else there is no such property if you have not declared one by yourself.

Comment: added full code.
How do I make it so?

Comment: just try this.controls.add(btn) instead controls.add(btn). If you are trying this in the code behind file of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is not inheriting from `System.Windows.Forms.Form`. So there is no such property called `Controls`.

What you can do is pass a reference of the form to the constructor of `SnakeB`:

```
public class SnakeB
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.Form parentForm;

    public SnakeB(System.Windows.Forms.Form parent)
    {
        parentForm = parent;
    }
}
```

and use it in your methods like this:

```
public Point getPoint()
{
    Button b = parentForm.Controls.Find(num + "") as Button;
    return b.Location;
}

public void addSnake(bool isFirst)
{
    Button b = new Button();
    // ...
    parentForm.Controls.Add(b);
}
```

Usage:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SnakeB snake = new SnakeB(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have instance of the form in your class and add the control to that instance like

```
public class SnakeB
{
    int num;
    int oneD;
    Point pos = new Point();
    Form1 frm1 = new Form1();



 frm1.Controls.Add(btn);
```

How will you have the instance of the form? Like below

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SnakeB snake = new SnakeB(this);
    }
```

In your class have a similar consructor

```
public class SnakeB
{
    int num;
    int oneD;
    Point pos = new Point();
    Form1 frm1;

    public SnakeB()
    {
        this.num = 0;
        this.oneD = 2;
        //here construct the maain head button and 2 reguler ones
        addSnake(true);
        addSnake(false);
        addSnake(false);
    }

    public SnakeB(Form1 frm) : this()
    {
        this.frm1 = frm;
    }
```

Comment: It creates a loop Loading 'Form1' over and over again which causes a stackoverflow